# How to automatically remove compiled styles after they're versioned in Elixir?

Tags: laravel, gulp, laravel-elixir

I use Laravel Elixir to merge and minify stylesheets. The problem is when I use versioning, it creates two identical copies:

#1

```
public/build/css/layout.css.map
public/build/css/layout-b94a608888.css
```

#2

```
public/css/layout.css
public/css/layout.css.map
```

How do I remove #2 copy automatically using Gulp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was already asked here: [Delete intermediary files after elixir merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29672474/delete-intermediary-files-after-elixir-merge)

They recommend using [npm del library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/del) and the code looks like this:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
var del = require('del');

elixir.extend('remove', function(path) {
    new elixir.Task('remove', function() {
        del(path);
    });
});

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.remove([ 'public/css', 'public/js' ]);
});
```